# how to change a specific element in onclick event using jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose I have table with individual **id** with each **td** and I want to add some effect or something when anyone click any **td** element for this particular **td** using **jquery**.

for example:

```
<table>
<tr>    
    <td id="11"> some text 1 </td>  
    <td id="12"> some text 2 </td>
    <td id="13"> some text 3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td id="21"> some text 4 </td>  
    <td id="22"> some text 5 </td>
    <td id="23"> some text 6 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now when anyone click on any of **td** for example, `td which id equal to 22` , I want to add some effect for example `( add background-color/color  etc )`

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("td").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
});
```

OR to target a specific td ONLY

```
$("#22").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wP32G/)

**Update**: I am guessing by `value` you mean the text inside the `td`? If so then you can use this

```
$(this).text();
```

OR

```
$("#id").text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wP32G/1/)

Comment: How can I get this td's value

Comment: Help vampire detected. Also, `<td>` elements do not have a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#22').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#f6ff00');
});
```

Or as an object (in case you want to change multiple properties):

```
$('#22').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#f6ff00'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can start learning jQuery here](http://learn.jquery.com/)

```
$('#22').on('click',function(){
  $(this).css({backgroundColor:'red'});
});
```

---

**Recommendation**: Don't start your id with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For a different effect on each `id` you  can do the following:

**JQuery**

```
$("td").on('click', function(){
    var tdid = $(this).attr('id'); //get the id of the td
    switch (tdid){
    case "11":
        $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
        break;
    case "12":
        $(this).css("background-color", "Green");
        break;
    case "13":
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        break;
        //... add the others here
    case "22":
        $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
        break;
    default:
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        break;

    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tr>    
  <td id="11"> some text 1 </td>  
  <td id="12"> some text 2 </td>
  <td id="13"> some text 3 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>    
  <td id="21"> some text 4 </td>  
  <td id="22"> some text 5 </td>
  <td id="23"> some text 6 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[**FIDDLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UUku/)

Comment: Actually this td's Id is generated dynamically from server, How can I get td's value? $(this).val() is not worked